# Как запустить Go программу в фоновом процессе?

Tags: golang

Платформа `Windows 64bit`. Как запустить `Golang` программу в фоновом процессе средствами Go? Нашел решение только под `Linux`, под `Windows` нечего не нашел. Может как-нибудь сервисом сделать, но тоже не знаю.

Comment: Что имеется в виду под фоновым процессом? Вам нужно чтобы программа консоль не показывала?

Comment: Вы пробовали пакет [`os/exec`](https://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/)? В документации лишь написано, что на Windows может работать не всё.

Comment: @kvark128 да, чтоб не показывало оболочку программы

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
go build -ldflags -H=windowsgui
```

Comment: Огромное Вам спасибо! С Наступающим!

Answer (score 0):

Для написания сервисов есть [package svc](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/sys/windows/svc).

Ещё можно сделать бесконечный цикл, чтобы приложение не закрылось, и запустить как сервис через `nssm`:

```
nssm install MyService с:\MyService.exe
```